# Select Top 1 In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Please help me in select top 1

The data like this

```
Code    Amp      Price
-----------------------
00001   10       1000
00002   75-100   1500
00003   50-60    1200
00004   15       1100
```

Note : datatype for column `Amp` is `VarChar`

I want to select with Amp 75 and I want get the price is 1500

So I use this statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Cable 
WHERE (Amp <= '75') 
ORDER BY Amp DESC
```

but the result price I get is 1200 is record with code : 00003 (wrong), actually I want the result is code : 00002 and the price is 1500

But if I want to select with Amp 76 the result is true with the syntax :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Cable 
WHERE (Amp <= '75') 
ORDER BY Amp DESC
```

What is the true select for my case? Please help me

Comment: That's not the correct way to store data. Normalize it

Comment: i know not the way to store data. But the case is like this.

Comment: data type issue... varchar is alphanumeric .. ranging it as a number won't do it.

Comment: break your amp to "amp from" and "amp to"... that's your range as numeric

Comment: What makes your current approach even worse is that you mix ranges with individual numbers.  This mean that a workaround will be very difficult.  You should seriously normalize your data.

Comment: i know the type data is wrong but the user already copy from old data to the new data and they won't to change because they said before their app  can why ur app cannot. Thank's for all ur advice

Comment: Create a table variable with numeric columns, move the data to that using SQL string functions to parse out the numeric bits, then select from the table variable.

Answer (score 2):

Just about any parse/split function will do, and combined with a Cross Apply, it becomes a small matter

-- Easy to do without a parse function

```
Declare @Cable table (Code varchar(25),Amp varchar(50),Price int)
Insert Into @Cable values
('00001','10',    1000),
('00002','75-100',1500),
('00003','50-60', 1200),
('00004','15',    1100)

Select Top 1 A.*
 From  @Cable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Amp,'-') B
 Where RetVal<=76              --<< Notice we are testing for 76
 Order By Price Desc
```

Returns

```
Code    Amp     Price
00002   75-100  1500
```

**The UDF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: `John||Cappelletti||was||here`?? LOL

Comment: @GurV Damn Straight !

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/breaking-bad-walter-white-bryan-cranston-U1XhGr8CWqvVC?utm_source=media-link&utm_medium=landing&utm_campaign=Media%20Links&utm_term=https://www.reddit.com/r/leafs/comments/62xtxo/the_leafs_are_actually_good/

Comment: @GurV Actually Lauged Out Loud ... thanks for that.  :)

Comment: Why this verbose answer is better than mine. Just want to know if I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @FLICKER Not better, just different... that said, you have a syntax issue isnumeric(...)=1  and you are only trapping left(2).  what happens when amp range is 150-300  ?

Comment: Thanks for feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to work with this existing datatype and table structure then below query may work for you.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Cable
WHERE (SUBSTRING(Amp,1,IIF((CHARINDEX('-',Amp)-1)>0,(CHARINDEX('-',Amp)-1),0 ) ) <=75)
ORDER BY Amp DESC
```

Comment: sir can u tell to me what sql server u use why i error in charindex?

Comment: I did that in 2012. Which version are you using? If it is prior to 2012 then query need some changes.

Comment: i still use sql 2000.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 and later, try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Cable 
WHERE isnumeric(left(Amp, 2)) = 1 and cast(left(Amp, 2) as int) <= 75
and Price = 1500 
ORDER BY Amp DESC
```

Note: This will work only if you have no records with Amp less than 10.

Comment: sir, if u think what must i do for the easy select for my case? I will try change the fields. The values not all like this 75-100 only little data like the conditions. Much data only 1 value like 10, 40,100 etc

Comment: My answer will work in both case . if your data is number like 10 or a range like 40-90 it will work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SQL Server is not going to sort a `varchar` column like an `int`.

**Sorting issue example:**

```
select *
from (
    select '125' as nbr
    union all
    select '24' as nbr
    ) as a
order by a.nbr asc
```

1 is less than 2 (the first character in each `nbr`), so it will sort thinking that 125 < 24 (not true), even though it looks pretty simple to anyone that 24 should show up first, which is how it would be sorted if the datatype of the column were an `int`.

What needs to happen is to split the `amp` column into ranges, or max and min. Using the `-` as the delimeter, you can use `charindex` to split the numbers up and `cast` them as `int`s instead.

**Sample Data Setup:**

```
declare @cable table
    (
        code char(5) not null
        , amp varchar(10) not null
        , price int not null
    )

insert into @cable
values 
        ('00001','10'       ,10000),
        ('00002','75-100'   ,15000),
        ('00003','50-60'    ,12000),
        ('00004','15'       ,11000)
```

**Answer:**

```
declare @amp_nbr int = 75

select top 1 *
from (  
    select c.code
    , cast(iif(charindex('-', c.amp, 0) > 0, left(c.amp, charindex('-', c.amp, 0) - 1), c.amp) as int) as amp_min
    , cast(iif(charindex('-', c.amp, 0) > 0, right(c.amp, len(c.amp) - charindex('-', c.amp, 0)), c.amp) as int) as amp_max
    , c.price
    from @cable as c
    ) as a
where 1=1
and @amp_nbr between a.amp_min and a.amp_max
order by a.amp_min desc
```

After that, a simple `between` constraint in the `where` clause will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for all answers. I decides to type all data and change it with two field.

### Code    Amp1      Amp2     Price

00001   10        10       1000
00002   75        100      1500
00003   50        60       1200
00004   15        15       1100

The single value i type same in field Amp2 and then i use the syntax :
SELECT * FROM Cable WHERE (65 BETWEEN Amp1 AND Amp2)